# How do I get Wand for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python-2.7, wand

I am trying to learn more about displaying graphics with Python 2.7.9 and one post on StackOverflow directed me to wand, but nowhere can I find how to install wand.  'sudo apt-get install wand' fails with 'Unable to locate package wand'.

http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/ says to install using '$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev' but any sample programs end in error with "no module named wand."

What I am trying to do is to flash a number on the console screen that is readable from across the room.  I am making an Easter Egg hunt game in Python which is mostly finished, but the numbers on the screen from print ("5") are just too small.  My thought was to just use Photoshop to make an image of the number then something like wand to display it instead of printing it to the screen.

So if Wand isn't the correct answer, suggestions would be appreciated.  If wand will work for my game display, how do I get it?

Thanks

Comment: `pip install Wand`, but it might be worth checking out [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). It'll save some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try pygame if you are doing game display. I tried it and it is very simple to learn. It is normally already downloaded on most python interpreters but if you for some reason do not have pygame, then go here; it teaches well and can help installing:

https://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter1.html

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of PyGame.  Apparently it's already in Jessie as I can import pygame in Python.  I tried a couple of sample Python scripts from the book, but the line 'from pygame.locals import *' returns an error "ImportError: No module named locals".  Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: @user3573562 There should be nothing inherently wrong with that line. Is it possible that you named your file `pygame.py` like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949362/2588654) SO question? That would certainly confuse the python interpreter as it would not be able to find `pygame.locals` since it would be looking in your code instead!

Comment: You don't have to do the pygame.locals thing, I never did.  Apparently it is supposed to "save you typing," but I don't understand how.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336206/can-someone-please-explain-this-weird-pygame-importing-convention

Comment: @CodeSurgeon and SnootierBaBoom- You are both correct, many thanks.  It never occurred to me to not name my test program the same as the module.  Removing the second import as Snootier suggested did, in fact, allow the program to run.  But, only after first renaming the script AND deleting the .pyc file.  Now back to the books to work on other errors.